# How do I pull the week of the month from text strings in this Twilio format 2019-08-22 06:12:58 MDT?

Tags: date, formula, google-sheets-formula

I am using the Twilio log file to crunch some data and need to convert the Twilio format for dates into something that Google Sheets can recognize as a date so I can then extract what week of the month the date is referring to. Also would be helpful to get the syntax that converts the Twilio date to a recognizable date for Googlesheets in case there are other things I need to do with the date field.

Currently, this is the format in the log file:  "2019-08-22 06:12:58 MDT"

I'm using this =text(index(split(I2," "),,1),"mmmm") to determine the month and am struggling to have this now be able to work with the WEEKNUM function of Googlesheets to get the number of the week the date is from. I've tried =DATE(index(split(I2," "),,1),"mmmm"), =WEEKNUM(index(split(I2," "),,1),"mmmm") but am terrible with the formula syntax and can't fix the date value.

=DATE(index(split(I2," "),,1),"mmmm")

I expect to see a value from 1-5.

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` part of the formula is turning the date input into text. And so you can't use it to calculate the `weeknum()`.

`=weeknum(index(split(I2," "),,1))` will get you closer. But it will give you the [week of the **year**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949).

You may want to [see this](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-current-months-week-number-in-google-sheets/) for a way to get to week of the month from week in the year.